# Whitelist hosted agent for azure app service with azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

We are use the hosted agent for deploying website to azure app service. By default we blacklist the scm part of the website and add a whitelist for the hosted agent so that it can update the website. But since version **2.10.1** of azure cli this does not seem to work anymore.

What we do is the following in azure cli:

```
az webapp config access-restriction add --resource-group 'Resource-group' --name 'webapp-name' --action Allow --priority 20 --ip-address '4.3.2.1/32' --rule-name 'Test1' --description 'Test1'

az webapp config access-restriction add --resource-group 'Resource-group' --name 'webapp-name' --action Allow --priority 20 --ip-address '4.3.2.1/32' --rule-name 'Test2' --description 'Test2' --scm-site $true
```

(were 4.3.2.1 is the ip address of the hosted agent)

if we run the second command we get an error back like this:

> cli.azure.cli.core.util : IP address 4.3.2.1/32 already exists.Cannot add duplicate IP address values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable the same rules for scm site you may use [this command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/access-restriction?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_access_restriction_set):

> Sets if SCM site is using the same restrictions as the main site.

```
az webapp config access-restriction set --use-same-restrictions-for-scm-site {false, true}
                                        [--ids]
                                        [--name]
                                        [--resource-group]
                                        [--slot]
                                        [--subscription]
```

You may also change an order, please first add to scm site then to main site.

I opened an issue on GitHub for this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/15198).

Comment: I have also created a [bug report](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/14862) but did not get any response yet. Thanks for the workaround, that should work indeed.

Comment: Oh. Cool I didn't know that.